# How do I find out why my emails were dropped by live.com?

Tags: email, postfix

I have set postfix to send mail, but haven't done it properly such as setting up ptr records, DomainKeys and Sender IDs. All the mail sent to gmail.com accounts get into Spam folders (which is fine), but live.com and msn users just don't receive it at all, nothing in Junk. Is it possible for live.com to drop mails entirely without user consent? MSN/Live.com is doing something that Google isn't doing.

EDIT:
From: http://mail.live.com/mail/junkemail.aspx

```
If a message has an SCL rating lower than a certain threshold, it is considered spam and a rule then deletes the message rather than send the message to the users’ junk e-mail folders.
```

Seems my mails have failed their Spam Confidence Level and just deletes it without sending it to the junk folder. What are the steps involved to increase SCL so that it at least gets into Junk other than to setup DomainKeys and so many details that are involved. I have already done PTR/rDNS and test it, doesn't' work yet.

Comment: Do you have SPF?
What is your Sender Score? Are you a member of JMRP?

Comment: I don't. Where do I check sender score? I am not part of JMRP (Had to google for what that was).

Comment: What does tell Postfix log?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly how to raise your SCL, but there are other steps you should make sure you have done to help prove you are who you say you are.

SPF/SenderId - http://www.openspf.org/

This is an explicit approval from your sending domain that this mail server is allowed to send mail on its behalf. It is setup as a simple DNS TXT entry, very quick and easy to do. You can tell if you have it set up properly in gmail by clicking the arrow next to reply on a message and selecting 'show original' then looking for

> Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xxx@your_domain.com designates [IP address] as permitted sender)

DKIM - dkim.org/

This is the other authentication scheme you should consider. You should do this with SPF, not in place of. This does require signing your message, but provides a level of security that your email wasn't spoofed by another domain.

best of luck! adam